# JavaScript const scope and curly braces

Tags: javascript, html

As I understand the scope of `const` is curly braces (block). However, when I run the following code in browser (FF) it doesn't give any error. Is the following JS code right? Please, explain.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 {
     const Foo = "foo";        
 }
 </script>
 <div></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 {
     Foo = null;
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: You said so yourself *scope of const is curly braces (block)*. Why would it give the error?

Comment: try console.log(Foo) insted of Foo =null , you will get error in console

Comment: @gurvinder372 because later I change Foo. What is the Foo in the second script?

Comment: In the next script `foo` has global scope since you didn't localized it using `var`, `let` or `const`.

Comment: add `use strict` (at the second <script> tag) and get the error :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will not get error because,

Below code says you are using const variable of `Foo` inside this code block, the `const Foo` will bot be accessible out side of the block

```
 {
     const Foo = "foo";        
 }
```

Below code says you are assigning the variable `Foo` with value of `null`, which will bind to `window` object,

```
 {
    Foo = null;
 }
```

so `Foo = null;` which binds to `window` object and `const Foo='foo'` is a constant variable for the particular code block

So when you are assign `Foo=null` it assigns the variable to `window` object and you can access it like ,

```
  window.Foo
```

i.e. any variable which declare without var it will bind to `window` object,

Comment: Good answer, I'd add to that on `strict` mode you'll get an error if not writing directly `var` or `window.`

Comment: @DanielKrom yes agreed, but for OP's code it will not

Comment: I feel that your answer is missing something essential: ie **why** there is no error. I do not see words about the use of the scope itself.

Answer (score 3):

You are aware that using `const` will create a constant in a given scope. Look at your example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
{
   const Foo = "foo";        
}
</script>
<div></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
{
   Foo = null;
}
</script>
```

You can reduce the above to the following code:

```
{
   const Foo = "foo";        
}
{
   Foo = null;
}
```

Since you have declared and initialized `Foo` in a scope (denoted by using `{` and `}`), then Foo is *only* known to that scope. Let's call that scope A. When issuing `Foo = null;`, you are in a different scope: B. When assigning a value to a variable, the engine always checks if the variable name is not bound in the current execution context. In short, it checks

1. if `Foo` exists in the **local scope**: the answer is no. Your `Foo = "foo"` is only known to the scope A. Not in the current scope.
2. if `Foo` exists in the **scope chain**: the answer is no. There is no declarations made in the parent scope.
3. if `Foo` is known to the **global execution context** (aka window scope): the answer is no.

End result: the assignment will occur. But since you did not have provided any assignment statements: `const`, `let` or `var`. Therefore, `Foo=null` will be added to the window scope. If you do `window.Foo`, you will get a response with `null`.

However, it has to be noted that there should be an error. But Javascript is a language that "serves" the developer. Instead of spitting you with an error, it will silent that error and hook `Foo` to the window object. If you use [`strict mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), then it will throw an error. (please consult the MDN page for further information)

To comprehend it a better, look to the following examples that is executed in a **non-strict** environment and think first if there would be an error or not.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
{
     const Foo = 'hello';
     Foo = 555; // success or fail ?
}
</script>
```

The answer is no. You are aware of that. It fails the first check: `Foo` is already bound in the same scope.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
{
     const Foo = 'hello';
     {
        Foo = 555; // success or fail ?
     }
}
</script>
```

The answer is yes. It will fail because it fails the second check (see the list above). `Foo = 555;` is called in a scope: B. Scope B has a parent scope: A where `Foo` is known.

Now, something tricky:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    {
        window.Foo = 'hello';
        {
            Foo = 555; // success or fail ?
        }
    }
</script>
```

What do you think?

...

**it works**. Do you not believe me: check it here below:

```js
{
  window.Foo = 'hello world';
  console.log('window.Foo?', window.Foo); // shows hello world
  {
    Foo = 555;
    console.log('window.Foo?', window.Foo); // shows 555
  }
}
```

that is because adding variables to the window scope (although it is not recommendable to do so) does not make it read-only. You can change it afterwards as desired.